# Cann't Visualize certain term in kibana data table

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I would like to list the count of certain message / code in kibana data table. In the buckets section, I select aggregation as "Terms" and select the property I would like to count in "Field". It works fine for some terms but not the others.

[image]
It is okay for "fields.MemberType.raw"

[image]

No result found if I select "fields.RestApiRequestAndResponse.Response.Message".

[image]

I can find both fields in discover.

Have no idea why no result found ... Any idea or how can I trace what happened? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the date filter correctly set when you are aggregating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the cause of the issue.. my colleague has update the template of the log... the field "fields.RestApiRequestAndResponse.Response" has map to "nested". :(